# Does the edge effect promote biodiversity?

Tags: ecology, biodiversity, habitat

I define the edge effect as:

*A term used to describe what occurs at habitat boundaries where two bordering communities influence one another.*

My question is whether it generally leads to an increase or decrease in biodiversity (both evenness and richness) and why.

Also, what are the biogeographic factors that impact biodiversity relating to this edge effect?

I believe that species diversity would increase, as at such habitat boundaries species that inhabit the bordering habitats and those that can also be found in habitat boundaries would be present.

I do remember reading that light intensity increases due to the edge effect and thus also allows for shade-intolerant species to thrive, but I do not understand why.

Comment: The question is interesting. The question might be considered as too broad but to even start thinking about the question we'll need a definition of [biodiversity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Biodiversity). Biodiversity can mean many different things. Did you mean number of species per square meter or something like that? There might have issues with what you would call "different communities" too. Also, if you can include thoughts (if any) and what you've found so far (if any), it may help.

Answer (score -2):

EDGE EFFECT PROMOTES BIODIVERSITY.
EDGE EFFECT OCCURS IN ECOTYPE.
ECOTYPE IS THE TRANSISSION ZONE WHERE TWO COMMUNITIES MERGE.
HENCE SPECIES RICHNESS IS FAIRLY HIGHER THAN THAT OF THE SURROUNDING ECOSYSTEMS.
IF ANY OF THE SPECIES TENDS TO EXPLOIT THE RESOURCES OF THE ECOTYPE IT WHOULD HAVE TO MODIFY ITS CHARACTERISTICS BY THE PROCESS OF  ADAPTIVE RADIATION AND EVOLUTION .
HENCE NEW SPECIES EMERGES PROMOTING BIODIVERSITY.

Comment: You have something that needs fixing.

Comment: Can you please edit your answer and fix the typing? All caps is hard to read.